# Include 2 conditions in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

i have this line:

```
logical= [value in line for value in Dictionnary["substance_name"].values]
```

that gave me this error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

This is probably due to some gaps in my dictionnary.

So to fix it I thought about adding this:

```
logical= [value in line for value in Dictionnary["substance_name"].values and value not None]
```

By the synthax seems to be incorrect. How can I express it correctly?
I edited my code:

```
logical= [value in line for value in DictionnaireMedicHUG["substance_name"].values] 
            if logical != None:
```

I am still getting the same error

Comment: Change `and` to `if`. Also, don't you mean `.values()`, rather than `.values`?

Comment: If I use `.values()` I get `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Comment: OK. I thought we were talking about a dictionary.

Comment: My bad it is actually a dataframe (pandas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
logical = [value in line for value in DictionnaireMedicHUG["substance_name"].values if logical is not None]
```

Comment: Did this help you? @marou95thebest